# Why is there a lag when consuming from Apache Kafka using Java KafkaConsumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I hope someone can shed some light on my issue.

I'm making a series of REST calls to a micro-service I have built. When the service receives the calls, it persists some data to a database and then publishes a message to a Kafka topic.

I'm trying to write a test that makes the REST calls and then consumes the messages from the Kafka topic.

When my test tries to consume from Kafka, it doesnt appear to be consuming the latest messages.

I've used the kafka-consumer-groups.sh shell script which ships with Kafka to describe the state of my consumer. Here is what it looks like:

```
bash-4.3# ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group test
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use the Java consumer API (non-ZooKeeper-based consumers).

Consumer group 'test' has no active members.

TOPIC         PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG  CONSUMER-ID  HOST  CLIENT-ID
test_topic    0          42              43              1    -            -     -
```

Note the lag of 1. This is what appears to be my issue.

Here is my Kafka consumer code:

```
public void consumeMessages() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

    try (KafkaConsumer < String, String > kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer < > (props)) {
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test_topic"));
        ConsumerRecords < String, String > consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(5000);
        for (ConsumerRecord < String, String > consumerRecord: consumerRecords) {
            System.out.printf("offset = %d, message = %s%n", consumerRecord.offset(), consumerRecord.value());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly received.

Thanks,

Ben :)

Comment: Is this a consistent behavior you're observing? I'm asking because normally the `poll()` call should be in a loop. With you code, you just do one poll and it's possible the single poll cannot consumer all the messages.

Comment: You are not manually committing offsets so you must be using the default auto commit interval of every 5 seconds. You also exit without committing offsets or calling close() so your application may have consumed all 43 messages but it exits before the next auto commit interval so your last committed offset is still the last successful commit of 42. You should call consumer.close() before exit

Comment: @vahid - Yes, this is consistent, I'm always one behind the last message.

Comment: @HansJespersen - I'm using Java's try with resources which auto closes the consumer the same way it would if I explicitly called consumer.close() in a finally block.

Comment: @BenBullock Can you try running the `poll()` call (and the following `for` loop) in a `while (true)` loop and see if you get a different result?

Comment: @vahid - I tried your suggestion and this worked! It seems I was consuming too early (i.e. before the message has been committed to Kafka). Polling in a loop ensures I receive the message. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: In Kafka you almost always poll in a loop